# How can I make duplicate functions into one in Reactnative?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have an array object called growthLengthImg and ecdysisInfoImg.
I also have states called upgrowthLengthImg, upecdysisInfoImg, degrowthLengthImg, and deecdysisInfoImg.

When updateFlag becomes true, I extracted the values ​​of growthLengthImg and ecdysisInfoImg and put the values ​​in the state using setUpgrowthLengthImg and setUpecdysisInfoImg.

At this time, when I execute deleteImgfunc1 or deleteImgfunc2 function, I extract the value of restImg, put it in the value of setUpgrowthLengthImg, and use setDegrowthLengthImg to save v.name.

But I think having two deleteImgfunc seems inefficient. This is because deleteImgfunc may increase further. So I want to merge deleteImgfunc into one and remove duplicates, but how do I do that?

this is my code

```
    growthLengthImg = [
            {
    byteSize: 20089,
    extension: "jpeg",
    name: "tes",
    originName: "growthLength 1",
            }
    ]



    ecdysisInfoImg = [
            {
    byteSize: 20086,
    extension: "jpeg",
    name: "asd",
    originName: "ecdysisInfo 2" ,
            }
    ]

    const [upgrowthLengthImg, setUpgrowthLengthImg] = useState([])
    const [upecdysisInfoImg, setUpecdysisInfoImg] = useState([])


    const [degrowthLengthImg, setDegrowthLengthImg] = useState([])
    const [deecdysisInfoImg, setDeecdysisInfoImg] = useState([])
    
    useEffect(() => {
            if (updateFlag) {
            const growthLengthImg = Images.filter((v: ImagesInfo) => v.originName.includes("growthLength"));
            const ecdysisInfoImg = Images.filter((v: ImagesInfo) => v.originName.includes("ecdysisInfo"));
            setUpgrowthLengthImg(growthLengthImg)
            setUpecdysisInfoImg(ecdysisInfoImg)
    
            }
    }, [updateFlag]);



    const deleteImgfunc1 = (value: string) => {

           //value : "tes"
            const restImg = upgrowthLengthImg.filter((v) => !v?.name.includes(value));
            setUpgrowthLengthImg([])
            setUpgrowthLengthImg(restImg);

    
            setDegrowthLengthImg([...degrowthLengthImg, value]);

    }


    const deleteImgfunc2 = (value: string) => {
            const restImg = upecdysisInfoImg.filter((v) => !v?.name.includes(value));
            setUpecdysisInfoImg([])
            setUpecdysisInfoImg(restImg);

    
            setDeecdysisInfoImg([...deecdysisInfoImg, value]);

    }


      return (
            <>
            <Pressable
            onPress={() => deleteImgfunc1?.(v?.name)}
            >
            </Pressable>


            <Pressable 
            onPress={() => deleteImgfunc2?.(v?.name)}
            >
            </Pressable>
            </>
             )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a generic func called deleteImage  and passs type as param, hope it helps, feel free for doubts

```js
const deleteImgfunc = (value: string, type:string) => {

                
                    if(type === "first_type"){
            const restImg = upgrowthLengthImg.filter((v) => !v?.name.includes(value));
        setUpgrowthLengthImg([])
        setUpgrowthLengthImg(restImg);


        setDegrowthLengthImg([...degrowthLengthImg, value]);
          }
          
          if(type === "second_type"){
           const restImg = upecdysisInfoImg.filter((v) => !v?.name.includes(value));
            setUpecdysisInfoImg([])
            setUpecdysisInfoImg(restImg);

    
            setDeecdysisInfoImg([...deecdysisInfoImg, value]);
          }
           

    }
    


and you can do onPress like this


<Pressable
            onPress={() => deleteImgfunc?.(v?.name,"first_type")}
            >
            </Pressable>


            <Pressable 
            onPress={() => deleteImgfunc?.(v?.name,"second_type")}
            >
            </Pressable>
```

Comment: but should i change   deleteImgfunc1 => deleteImgfunc and deleteImgfunc2 => deleteImgfunc in Pressable component?

Comment: yes sorry forgot to update that

Comment: done :) now do check